# Get SharePoint people picker value in List Item Updating After properties

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a requirement that I have to get the list item values in SharePoint list item updating event. In that I am getting list item properties( current properties ) and also updated values( after properties ), except the people picker value.

as that

```
string cuurentUser= properties.ListItem["User"].ToString();
( Result: "22;#RAMPINDIA/ventew")
string afterUser= properties.AfterProperties["PermissionLevel"].ToString(); (Result:"22")
```

as shown above I am just getting the ID only.

Can any one help me to find the way to find the entire name?

Comment: Based on your sample, it would seem that you aren't reading the before and after values from the same field... Is that right?

Comment: yes, in after properties iam reading all fields except the people picker value...

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing to lookup field in AfterProperties, you always get only lookup id. User field is also lookup to User Information List, so you must get user using GetById(int ID) as @Stuart Pegg suggests. But there are some pitfalls when you accessing to lookup fields in event receivers, I've posted about this pitfalls in my blog, check it out:

[Accessing SharePoint lookup fields values in item receivers - some pitfalls](http://spblog.net/post/2011/07/06/Accessing-SharePoint-lookup-fields-values-in-item-receivers-some-pitfalls.aspx)
[Working with SPFielduserValue in item event receivers - some pitfalls](http://spblog.net/post/2011/07/07/Working-with-SPFielduserValue-in-item-event-receivers-some-pitfalls.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to use the `SPWeb.AllUsers.GetById(int ID)` method to get the `SPUser` for that ID, and then use that object's properties to get the required information:

[MSDN: SPUserCollection.GetByID Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.getbyid.aspx)

[MSDN: SPUser Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_members.aspx)

Also, you can use `SPFieldUserValue(SPWeb, string)` constructor to get an `SPFieldUserValue` object from your current properties string, and use `SPFieldUserValue.User` to get an SPUser object. More details on using `SPFieldUserValue` can be found on my blog:

[TssTssT: Easily accessing Lookup and User fields](http://tsstsst.com/easily-accessing-lookup-and-user-fields/)